# Metaplex findAllByCreator does not return all results

Tags: solana, metaplex

When I call metaplex.nfts().findAllByCreator(creatorKey) I get as a result approximately 1/4 of the actual amount of nfts that are created by that creatorKey (collection).
If a collection has 10K supply on Magic Eden the endpoint only returns +-2.5K nfts.
Why am I not getting all the results?
I am connecting to: "https://solana-api.projectserum.com" RPC. Could this have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the RPC can be the issue. You should use a private one or at least one that is more reliable like

https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net/

Comment: That RPC returns the error: " 403 Forbidden: Call type exceeds Solana 1.9.13 version limit for max account size."